# How can i convert my Delphi.NET project to Delphi Prism?

Tags: delphi, migration, delphi-prism, delphi.net

There's a project of mine wrotten in Delphi.NET, and i want it to be run in Linux (which will be Ubuntu, or RedHat), and i have to convert it to Delphi Prism.

So how can i convert it from Delphi.NET to Delphi Prism without doing lots of grunt work? I've try the Oxidizer, but it seems to be not the right one.

Any other suggestions?

Thank you.

Comment: you'll be be needing to do the grunt work. It should be pretty easy though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no perfect Automated method to convert from Delphi.NET to Prism.

You do mention.. [Oxidizer](http://code.remobjects.com/p/oxidizer/) it's current the best method to covert code.
[ShineOn](http://code.remobjects.com/p/shineon/) can also help by providing a subset of the RTL/VCL code to assist you in conversion.

However, there is nothing that will remove the need to do some grunt work.